# How can I take advantage of CircleCI parallelism in my Java / Maven / Surefire project?

Tags: java, junit, junit4, maven-surefire-plugin, circleci

I have a Java project that uses Maven and the [`maven-surefire-plugin`](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/) to run JUnit 4 tests. I'm building with [CircleCI](https://circleci.com/). How can I enable [parallelism](https://circleci.com/docs/how-parallelism-works) so that my test suite runs faster?

I want to use the CircleCI parallelism, not [Surefire fork and parallel execution](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/fork-options-and-parallel-execution.html) options.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The maven-surefire-plugin supports its doesn't support parallelism, at least not in isolated fashion CircleCI supports (separate nodes for each test execution).

However, you can manually enable CircleCI-style parallelism using two methods:

1. Use a shell script to select the tests to run per-node, and then using the `-Dtest` parameter.
2. Custom JUnit 4 `TestRule`

### Shell Script

Create a `bin` directory in your project, if you don't already have one.

In `bin`, create a shell script in your project called `test.sh`, with the following contents

```bash
#!/bin/bash

NODE_TOTAL=${CIRCLE_NODE_TOTAL:-1}
NODE_INDEX=${CIRCLE_NODE_INDEX:-0}

i=0
tests=()
for file in $(find ./src/test/java -name "*Test.java" | sort)
do
  if [ $(($i % ${NODE_TOTAL})) -eq ${NODE_INDEX} ]
  then
    test=`basename $file | sed -e "s/.java//"`
    tests+="${test},"
  fi
  ((i++))
done

mvn -Dtest=${tests} test
```

This script will search your `src/test/java` directory for all files ending in `Test.java`, and add them to the `-Dtest` parameter as a comma separated list, then call maven.

To enable your new test script, put the following in your `circle.yml` file:

```yaml
test:
  override:
    - ./bin/test.sh:
        parallel: true
```

Things to note:

1. You may need to customize this script if your filenames don't follow this naming convention, your files are located somewhere else, or you need to run a different lifecycle phase.
2. If you have a very many number of tests, you may find your `-Dtest` parameter exceeds the maximum length of the Linux command line.

### Junit4 TestRule

You can use a custom TestRule to do something similar to the above in Java code. This has the advantage of less CircleCI customized-configuration, but imposes some assumptions about CircleCI on your Java framework.

```
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import org.junit.Assume;
import org.junit.rules.TestRule;
import org.junit.runner.Description;
import org.junit.runners.model.Statement;

@Slf4j
final class CircleCiParallelRule implements TestRule {
    @Override
    public Statement apply(Statement statement, Description description) {

        boolean runTest = true;

        final String tName = description.getClassName() + "#" + description.getMethodName();

        final String numNodes = System.getenv("CIRCLE_NODE_TOTAL");
        final String curNode = System.getenv("CIRCLE_NODE_INDEX");

        if (StringUtils.isBlank(numNodes) || StringUtils.isBlank(curNode)) {
            log.trace("Running locally, so skipping");
        } else {
            final int hashCode = Math.abs(tName.hashCode());

            int nodeToRunOn = hashCode % Integer.parseInt(numNodes);
            final int curNodeInt = Integer.parseInt(curNode);

            runTest = nodeToRunOn == curNodeInt;

            log.trace("currentNode: " + curNodeInt + ", targetNode: " + nodeToRunOn + ", runTest: " + runTest);

            if (!runTest) {
                return new Statement() {
                    @Override
                    public void evaluate() throws Throwable {
                        Assume.assumeTrue("Skipping test, currentNode: " + curNode + ", targetNode: " + nodeToRunOn, false);
                    }
                };
            }
        }

        return statement;
    }
}
```

(Note I am using [Project Lombok](http://projectlombok.org) (log instantiation) and [Apache Commons-Lang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) (for StringUtils) in the above code, but these can easily be eliminated if necessary.

To enable this, in your test baseclass you can do this to balance on a test-by-test basis:

```
// This will load-balance across multiple CircleCI nodes
@Rule public CircleCiParallelRule className = new CircleCiParallelRule();
```

Or if you want to balance class-by-class, you can do this:

```
// This will load-balance across multiple CircleCI nodes
@ClassRule public CircleCiParallelRule className = new CircleCiParallelRule();
```